# Importing shapefile into Mapit

Tags: shapefile, import, android, mapit

Unable to import an ESRI generated shapefile (just a simple polygon layer) into the Android app.  MapIT does not recognize the file(s) in the upload screen, I can not select nor view it.  I have uploaded a folder and .zip file both the same name as the .shp and support files.  I also have modified a different point shapefile originally generated by MapIT with ArcMap then attempted to import the modified shapefile, no luck there either.

Problem solved by simply loading files onto device or dropbox.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to include answers to any comments. To confirm, all of the .shp .shx etc files are stored within the .zip? Where is the data stored on your device? (Mapit->Import folder?)  What device are you using? How many records are in the shapefile? (Questions based on this link: https://mapitgis.com/import-from-file/)

Comment: Yes, all the associated files are in the .zip.  The data is stored on google drive, and I'm using a Kyocera Duraforce running Android 7.1.2 (Nougat)... and just 1 record

Comment: Is there anything in the Mapit->Import folder?  I ask because of this quote:  "To import the data please copy your file to Mapit->Import folder on your device and access the import menu from layers’ context menu:"

Comment: Can not see anything... actually CAN see and use the .shp files when I load them into dropbox, though still can not see them on google drive.  I suppose this is just some quirk with the app and/or my OS

Comment: Now I have a different problem, the imported .shp files do not load correctly in the app, I'll start another question about this.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the files are loaded into the correct location on your device.

Per http://mapitgis.com/import-from-file: "To import the data please copy your file to Mapit->Import folder on your device and access the import menu from layers’ context menu". The data may not be visible from Google Drive; check support documentaton for the application.